# how to make test fail for one-to-one relationship in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I want to make one-to-one relationship in grails and to TEST it. So i created two classes.

There are two classes below.

```
class Book {

  String title
  Date releaseDate
  String ISBN

  static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
```

```
class Person {

  Book book;

  String name
  Integer age
  Date lastVisit

  static constraints = {
    book unique: true  // "one-to-one". Without that = "Many-to-one".
  }

}
```

And write the test:

```
public void testOneToOne() {
 Person person1 = new Person(name:"person_b1", age: 99, lastVisit: new Date())
      Person person2 = new Person(name:"person_b2", age: 100, lastVisit: new Date())

      Book oneBook = new Book(title:"somebook", ISBN: "somebook1", releaseDate: new Date())

      person1.setBook(oneBook)
      person1.save()

      person2.setBook(oneBook)
      person2.save()  // ! c'est impossible pour 'one-to-one'
}
```

So if this is on-to-one I'm NOT able to save person2 to db because one book can not be linked to more then one Person. So should i got an exception while do person2.save() then ?

I don't have. And person2 is not saving to db. So how can i test that - how to make test fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unique` constraint is used to ensure that one instance of a class can only be joined to a single instance of another class:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html

In your example you are joining one instance of Book to two instances of Person, i.e. a one to many association - so it makes sense that the save should fail. If you inspect the `person2.errors.allErrors` property you should see the `Person.book.unique` constraint has been violated.

This is what the one-to-one association test would look like - `person2` needs her own book, as you have declared that a book can only belong to one person with the `unique` constraint.

```
   public void testOneToOne() {
        Person person1 = new Person(name:"person_b1", age: 99, lastVisit: new Date())
        Person person2 = new Person(name:"person_b2", age: 100, lastVisit: new Date())

        Book oneBook = new Book(title:"somebook", ISBN: "somebook1", releaseDate: new Date())
        Book twoBook = new Book(title:"anotherbook", ISBN: "somebook2", releaseDate: new Date())

        person1.setBook(oneBook)
        assertNotNull(person1.save())

        person2.setBook(twoBook)
        assertNotNull(person2.save())
  }
```

It looks like you actually want a one (book) to many (people) association, so just leave the `unique` constraint out.

Comment: no, i want one book for one person. i just wondered why person2.save() does not throw an exception.

Comment: Ah - in that case my answer was a bit longwinded! Save returns the saved domain object if validation & save were successful and null if not, so `assertNull(person2.save()` answers the question. You can have `save` throw an exception with `person2.save(failOnError:true)`. You could even make that the default behaviour by setting `grails.gorm.failOnError=true` in Config.groovy. Take a look here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html